# How to use Github in xampp htdocs

Tags: git, xampp

I work as a collaborate in github and I'm cloning the repo. I use xampp for a website and I need to have my files in htdocs in xampp file. What can I do to fix it? Any ideas?

I have tried to push new data but when I do that I can't do the push command from there, only from a file I have on desktop where I cloned the repo.

> fatal: No configured push destination. Either specify the URL from the
>   command-line or configure a remote repository using

I expect to push my data but I couldn't from that file in htdocs

Comment: Why not perform the checkout within `htdocs`? Why not change the configuration to add a new VHost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood the problem properly, you aren't able to push your changes to the remote repository, from your local project located under the xampp directory.
And you're getting that error.
The error you're getting is that git finds the git repository, but doesn't find anything to push to. 
First you need to set the remote repository url after cloning it using:
`git remote set-url origin "git repository url.git`
You need to set the "destination of your push", meaning the upstream in your first push using: 
`git push -u origin your_branch`